# Did Rogue and Gajeel ever meet before the Tournament?

Tags: fairy-tail

In chapter 318, Gajeel mentions Rogue's real name, R(e)yos.

[image]

So what's the deal between them? I thought Rogue only adored/feared Gajeel from the shadows (pun not intended). So how did he know his real name?

Comment: I think we did not get any more information about them so far, so you'll have to wait until they give us more. I find it unlikely to happen though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In episode 13 of Fairy Tail (2014) Gajeel implies that he was a mentor to Rogue. The fact that he knew the name Reyos proves that Gajeel knew about him while in Phantom Lord. Gajeel says that Rogue was his disciple. According to the Fairy Tail wiki, Rogue is also Gajeels sworn younger brother but the wiki doesn't say how it got this info about the brother.

From the [wiki](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Gajeel_Redfox#History):

> At some point in time, Gajeel joined Phantom Lord. During his time in Phantom Lord, a young man named **Rogue Cheney**, **known as Ryos, was Gajeel's sworn younger brother**.

Comment: Could you provide a source reference to where in the wiki you read this?

Comment: http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Gajeel_Redfox     It's in the history section.

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly be so due to Gajeels ability to absorb Rouge's shadows. If Rouge was his disciple/brother, he was around he for an amount of time where he adapted to his magic.

Answer (score 0):

I think Rouge is Gajeel's younger brother since there is no other explanation I can think of. As we all know, when Gajeel was in Phantom Lord, he was feared so much. Therefore, he is respected but never admired.

It seems that Gajeel knows Rouge's real name since they were brothers and this would explain why Rouge respects Gajeel so much. Even Gajeel says that he is his disciple since they were brothers but with Gajeel as the older sibling and with Rouge as the younger sibling in the family.